# Android studio error while creating project with NDK support

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-2.2

I tried to create simple android application with NDK support. I followed `https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#new-project` while creating project. After creating project it gives me following error:

```
    External Native Build Issues
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HD:\AndroidNDKExample\app -BD:\AndroidNDKExample\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\AndroidNDKExample\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=19 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions}
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at C:/Users/Nilesh.Kashid/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/android.toolchain.cmake:351 (message):
  Failed to parse Android NDK revision:
  C:/Users/Nilesh.Kashid/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/source.properties.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Nilesh.Kashid/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Error:executing external native build for cmake D:\AndroidNDKExample\app\CMakeLists.txt
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HD:\AndroidNDKExample\app -BD:\AndroidNDKExample\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\AndroidNDKExample\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Nilesh.Kashid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=19 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions}
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at C:/Users/Nilesh.Kashid/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/android.toolchain.cmake:351 (message):
  Failed to parse Android NDK revision:
  C:/Users/Nilesh.Kashid/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/source.properties.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Nilesh.Kashid/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Error:executing external native build for cmake D:\AndroidNDKExample\app\CMakeLists.txt
```

I have downloaded CMake and LLDB android I am using Android Studio 2.2.3 version.

Comment: Is that really a off topic issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This problem occurs in older versions of ndk.

Failed to parse Android NDK revision:

The problem was resolved after updating ndk.
The current ndk version is 13.1.3345770.

Reference :
[https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html)

Comment: It appears that your reference is missing. Did you forget to add it?

Comment: Your link is broken